# How to add each value of an array in db as each row in yii

Tags: yii

```
    $usrmodel = new Tempcategory;

    $temp_id   = $tempid;
    $ct_id     = $ctid;


    $inarray=array();        

    if(is_array($inarray))
     {  
        foreach(array($ct_id) as $catid)            
        {   
           $inarray[]=array('temp_id'=>$temp_id,'ct_id'=>$catid); 

        }  

        if(count($inarray)>0)
        {
            GeneralRepository::insertSeveral($usrmodel->tableName(),$inarray);

        } 

    }
```

I have three tables..

> 1. category
>      ct_id primary
>      ct_name
> 2. template
>      temp_id primary
>      t_name
> 3. tempcategory
>      temp_cid primary
>      ct_id fk
>      temp_id fk

i need to save in db as follows

```
temp-id  ct_id
 1        1
 1        2
 1        3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $usrmodel = new Tempcategory;

    $temp_id   = $tempid;
    $ct_id     = $ctid;

    $new = explode(" ", $ct_id);
   // print_r($new);

    $inarray=array(); 

        foreach($new as $catid)            
        {                   
           $inarray[]=array('temp_id'=>$temp_id,'ct_id'=>$catid);               
        }  
        if(count($inarray)>0)
        {
            GeneralRepository::insertSeveral($usrmodel->tableName(),$inarray);
        }
```

Its Solved.........